# Deriving Rutherford Scattering Angle expression

Tags: physics, conic-sections

OK, this was an assignment and I want to be sure I am on the right track here. It's math as much as physics.

We want to find an expression for $\theta$, the Rutherford scattering angle.

I have an expression that I derived for a hyperbolic trajectory, of the form $\frac{(x+x_0)^2}{A^2}-\frac{y^2}{B^2} = 1$. We wanted it in terms of α, ε, where α is a constant ($ \alpha = \frac{L^2}{mk}$) and  $ \frac{\alpha}{r} = 1 + \epsilon \cos \theta$.

So what I got was:

$$ \left( x -  \frac{\alpha \epsilon}{(\epsilon^2-1)} \right)\frac{(\epsilon^2-1)}{\alpha^2} - \frac{y^2(\epsilon^2-1)}{\alpha^2} =1 $$.

Well an good, I thought. Anyhow, the next bit is deriving an equation for the scattering angle, knowing that the asymptotes are $y = \pm \tan \left(\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}\right)(x+x_0)$.

I have $(x+x_0)$, that's $ \left( x -  \frac{\alpha \epsilon}{(\epsilon^2-1} \right)$.

so if I want θ i first solved for $\tan \left(\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}\right)$.

I got:

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}\right) = \frac{y}{x+x_0} = \frac{y}{\left( x -  \frac{\alpha \epsilon}{\epsilon^2-1}\right)} = \frac{y(\epsilon^2-1)}{x(\epsilon^2-1)+\alpha \epsilon}$$

From there it seems to me I need to solve for θ. The simplest thing seemed to be to take an inverse tangent of the rather messy expression on the right. But I suspect something else is wanted here. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Otherwise Id have tried treating $\tan ((\theta - \pi)/2)$ as $\frac{-\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos \theta}$ on the left and substituting in the conversion to cartesian coordinates for cos θ, and then take an inverse sine of the (again) messy stuff on the right.

Anyhow, if anyone can tell me if I am doing something wrong that would be much appreciated, and I thank you.

Comment: Very important subtle error: if you're shifting the origin to $(x_0,0)$, then you're initial equation for the hyperbola in canonical form should be $\frac{(x - x_0)^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ with a minus sign between $x$ and $x_0$, not a plus sign.

Comment: I left it that way because that was how it was stated in the original problem. But noted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$\frac \alpha r=1+\epsilon \cos\theta\quad \quad (\epsilon>1)$$ one gets for $r\rightarrow \infty$ $$\theta=\pm \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac 1\epsilon \right)$$that are the directions of the asymptotes.
Remember that $$\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac 1\epsilon \right) \in \left[\frac \pi 2,\pi \right]$$The *scattering angle* $\Theta$ is defined by $$\Theta=2\,\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac 1\epsilon \right)-\pi$$and is the angle between the asymptotes.
Remember that $$\epsilon^2=\frac {2L^2E}{mk^2}+1$$